# How can I find the radius of convergence, where $a_n$ equal to number of divisors of $n^{50}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, power-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n z^{n}$ be a power series with $a_n$ equal to number of divisors of $n^{50}$. How can I find the radius of convergence.

My efforts.

$\beta=\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_n/a_{n+1}|$. Using this I got the answer 1.

But the books says answer is zero. I am confused. I think there is a printing mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since each $a_n$ is at least $1$, the series diverges when $z=1$ and therefore the radius of convergence is *at most* $1$.

On the other hand, $n^{50}$ has at most $n^{50}$ divisors and therefore $a_n\leqslant n^{50}$. So,$$\limsup\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leqslant\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{n^{50}}=1.$$Therefore, the radius of convergence is *at least* $1$.

Conclusion: …

Comment: so I have a bound for radius of convergence. How do I show that it is zero as mentioned in the book.

Comment: @MathamanTopologius Let me see if I got it right. I have just proved that the answer is $1$ and now you ask me to prove that the answer is $0$. Is that it?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. You are right. I got it.

Comment: Yeah I was going to do that. it cleared my doubt. Thank a lot for helping me out